# How to get stream link from google drive

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

I want to get stream link from google drive without playing it on web browser. The format link like this. 
https://r6---sn-npo7zn7k.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback..

Here is drive link demo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_ZB_L8pVIkejU1ai1GNmhKa0k/view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/js#prerequisites).

In the tutorial quickstart, it will explain how to use the Drive Rest API in JavaScript and the essential things to do like turning on the Drive API, creating the client ID for the OAuth, etc.

Here is the part of the sample code that you will see in the quickstart:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Your Client ID can be retrieved from your project in the Google
// Developer Console, https://console.developers.google.com
var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';

var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];

/**
* Check if current user has authorized this application.
*/
function checkAuth() {
gapi.auth.authorize(
{
'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
'immediate': true
}, handleAuthResult);
}
```

Then you will extract the value of `webViewLink`.

> *webViewLink*
>
> - A link only available on public folders for viewing their static web assets (HTML, CSS, JS, etc) via Google Drive's Website Hosting.

Here is a sample [response](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files):

```
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": string,
"etag": etag,
"selfLink": string,
"webContentLink": string,
"webViewLink": string,
"alternateLink": string,
"embedLink": string,
"openWithLinks": {
(key): string
},
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API from GetLinkDrive:

Ex: `http://api.getlinkdrive.com/getlink?url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6VYU2mjTdy0WVRjb1BJUU1hYXM/view`

The API will response stream link as below:

```
[{"label":720,"type":"video/mp4","src":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=19e3c7fd6fd45f15&itag=22&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1481719234&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=97E76D059F08E8B3B3C37FDE840C6B3978ACDD0C.8AF257B52254C7F116E658D6C52A3C5C3244EF75&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7s&ms=au&mt=1481704609&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","file":"https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=19e3c7fd6fd45f15&itag=22&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=api.getlinkdrive.com&ip=139.162.5.123&ipbits=0&expire=1481719234&sparams=requiressl,id,itag,source,ttl,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=97E76D059F08E8B3B3C37FDE840C6B3978ACDD0C.8AF257B52254C7F116E658D6C52A3C5C3244EF75&key=ck2&mm=31&mn=sn-npoe7n7s&ms=au&mt=1481704609&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnNpbjExKgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=22&safm=0&filename=video.mp4","res":720}]
```